# Add card to apple wallet in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, wallet, apple-wallet

Is there anyway to use PKAddPaymentConfiguration button from native ios in flutter?. I have tried to look for libraries to solve my problem but I can't seem to find a library that has this feature. I could only find libraries that adds passes/loyalty cards to wallet. Does anyone here knows of a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm struggling to find a library that will even add a pass card - there are two that appear that they might on the surface, but don't actually add to the wallet, and assume that the pass is defined at a URL rather than allowing it to be set locally.

Comment: So does this means that this add to wallet feature is not available yet for flutter development?